# my functions are mixed and the engine executing what ever he wants

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous

so i was told to   `Present a loader to the user when a call is made to the server (indicating the server is calculating) Present an error to the user if the input number is more than 50, and do not send a server request Try passing the number 42 to the server. The server will send back an error, present this error to the user.`

now what i did is everything besides the last error to present it to the user.
i have tried everything i could think of, and no matter what the user types, it displays both of the messages.

this is my code:

```
const clcBtn = document.getElementById("calcButton");
let clcInput = document.getElementById("calcInput");
const result = document.getElementById('paragraph');
const loader = document.getElementById('spinner');
const error = document.getElementById('error-message');
const serverError = document.getElementById('server-error');


clcBtn.addEventListener("click", calcFunc);

function numValidate(value) {
  if(value > 50) {
    return false;
  } 
  
  return true;
}


function calcFunc() {
  if (!numValidate (clcInput.value)) {
    error.style.display = "block"
    setTimeout(() => {
      error.style.display = "none";
    }, 5000);
    console.error("Can't be larger than 50") // only bec it's a cool feature :D
    
    return;
  }


  
  
  loader.classList.add("spinner-border");
  
  fetch(`http://localhost:5050/fibonacci/${clcInput.value}`).then(function (response) {
    return response.json().then(function (data) {
      result.innerHTML = data.result;
    });
  });
  
  
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    loader.classList.remove("spinner-border");
  }, 1000);
}
```

this is my code with what i have tried to add (on of the things i have tried.. this is the best output i could come with)
code:

```
  // additional code to present to the user the error message if the input value is equal to 42.
  clcBtn.addEventListener("click", errMsg);
  function numValidateTwo(value) {
    if(value === 42) {
      return true;
      } 
      return false;
  }
  function errMsg() {
    if (!numValidateTwo (clcInput.value)) {
      serverError.style.display = "block";
    }
    return;
  }
```

a little bit more about what i am trying to achieve:

i want to present this error message to the user, whenever the input value is equal to 42.

is it related to async or callback? which i need to go through the lectures again.. but right now i need to solve this bec i have no time.

what did i do wrong ?
and how i can make it work?
can someone explain this to me?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Anyone?
if there is anything i did not provide please let me know.